# F# regular expression string pattern change meaning

Tags: f#

I have another question for regular expression in F#:

```
let tagName = "div"
let ptnTagNotClose = "<" + tagName + "(>|\s+[^>]*>)[^<]"
```

I want to find the matches for not closing tag in HTML file.  The pattern string works in VB.NET.
But for F#, when I debug the above code, I can see the value for ptnTagNotClose:

```
ptnTagNotClose "<div(>|\\s+[^>]*>)[^<]"
```

F# automatically change "\s+" to "\\s+", but for regular expression,  "\s+" and "\\s+" are different, the results are also different.
Please let me know what to do to avoid F# automatically change the string pattern.

Verbatim string literal could be one solution, but since the tagName can change, i.e. let tagName = "br", then how I can apply verbatim string literal in this case?

Thanks!

John

Comment: At this point I feel compelled to point out that it is generally considered [a very bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/24380) to parse HTML or XML with regular expressions.

Comment: What does the fact that `tagName` can change have to do with verbatim string literals? Those are completely orthogonal issues...

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, using regular expression, people can extract some useful information from HTML.  For well-formatted XML, no need to use regular expression, as there are enough tools to get the useful information.  I know it is not easy to get all the information from HTML by regular expression.  But as long as I can get the information necessary for my other part of program running, I think it is enough!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the debug output means what you think it does; using a verbatim string (like `"<" + tagName + @"(>|\s+[^>]*>)[^<]"`) will give you the exact same result because `\s` isn't a valid escape sequence, so F# interprets the backslash as a literal backslash rather than an escape character.

Comment: Hi, KVB: I found the issue: inside VS2010 IDE, the debug result for the pattern was wrong, but from F# interactive, the result for the pattern was correct.  But it seems there are many difference between string/regular expression for VB.NET and for F#; therefore, the correct in VB.NET can not be reproduced in F#.

Comment: Hi,
I still believe that Regex in F# works differently than Regex in VB.NET.
If some one can try to use Regex in F# to extract some table elements in HTML  file, you will understand it.  But using Regex in VB.NET usually works!